# C# - why is Thread.Suspend() so bad?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Title says it all. I am running a Selenium web testing script that I want the ability to pause on user button click. Thread.Suspend() works perfectly, but I keep seeing everywhere about how you shouldn't use it, but no one really goes into to much detail as to WHY you shouldn't use it.

Are there circumstances where it really isn't THAT bad, but it's just one of those things that you probably shouldn't get into the habit of using?

Or will the world seriously end if I use thread.suspend to temporarily halt a simple script?

In my case I want the thread to halt IMMEDIATELY upon user button click. All of the other solutions to avoiding thread.suspend() using flags and whatnot just don't work quite as I want them to in this situation.

So can someone explain to me why thread.suspend() is such a bad idea if all i'm doing is running a simple script?

Comment: The question is answered right in the documentation of the method in question.  What about it didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Suspend_and_Resume

> From .NET 2.0, Suspend and Resume have been deprecated, their use discouraged because of the danger inherent in arbitrarily suspending another thread. If a thread holding a lock on a critical resource is suspended, the whole application (or computer) can deadlock. This is far more dangerous than calling Abort — which results in any such locks being released (at least theoretically) by virtue of code in finally blocks.
>
> It is, however, safe to call Suspend on the current thread — and in doing so you can implement a simple synchronization mechanism — ith a worker thread in a loop, performing a task, calling Suspend on itself, then waiting to be resumed (“woken up”) by the main thread when another task is ready. The difficulty, though, is in determining whether the worker is suspended.

I'll add that the last part is true only if you know that you don't have locks. This could be quite complex (if you suspend in method C that is called from method B and from method A, can you be sure that both method B and method A aren't locking anything?). But this problem, in general, exists even if you want to have multiple locks at the same time: creating a deadlock is always possible unless you are very good *and* very methodic.

Comment: ok, so by "locks" do you just mean the lock statement? it's probably clear from my question but i'm not super knowledgeable about c#, or threading in general. if by locks you DO mean lock statements, then i know i don't have any locks. so does that mean that thread.suspend() would not be the end of the world if i used it?

Comment: @kdeez By locks I mean any thing that can lock-and-wait... `lock` (that is `Monitor`), all the various `WaitHandle`, `Semaphore`s...

Comment: Well ok, yeah I'm definitely not using any of that stuff. And after implementing thread.suspend() and thread.resume() and testing it out a decent amount, nothing critically wrong seems to be occurring. so does that mean that I'm probably ok? Aside from, you know, committing the cardinal sin of going against best practice.

Comment: @kdeez Is the thread self-suspending? If yes, then there shouldn't be any problem. The `Thread.Resume()` is problem-free :-)

Comment: yes it is self suspending!! that's why i was curious as to why everyone seems to think thread.suspend() is the end of the world. but, i suppose it isn't if you're only dong a 1-track simple task like i am. thanks for the responses good sir, i appreciate it.